# Get caller element from jquery plugin function

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have the following jquery plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {

    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    componentId = settings.componentId;
    containerId = settings.containerId;


     $.fn.textarea = function( options ) {

       //....

       return this.each(function() {
          //.....
       )};

       $.fn.textarea.destroy = function() {
         //....
       };

    };
})( jQuery );
```

The problem is that when i use multiple instances of the plugin i can't pick the ID of the element i want to use, both `componentId` and `containerId` have the last value i used when creating the elements. I want to get the ID of the element from where im calling the function. Example:

```
$('#callerID').textarea.destroy();

$.fn.textarea.destroy = function() {
   //Here i want to get the ID of the element ACTUALLY calling the function inside the plugin
}
```

EDIT: Im trying not to pass parameters....

Comment: The question is why you would create such a structure, why not just `$('#callerID').textarea('destroy')` where you catch the `destroy` argument, and `this` would still be the element.

Comment: Hello, because each element could have a different `destroy` method, with different implementations...